# Change the content of a div in IE8 using javascript

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to change the content of the div using javascript/jquery. While the code works on IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera. It fails on IE 8. I have already tried .append, .appendTo, .innerHTML. The content of the container div is always empty

What could be wrong. The code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
function()
{
var containers = jQuery('.page_content');


if (!containers.length)
{
return
}
var container = containers.eq(0);

container.block();
jQuery.get("<?php echo Router::url( array('controller' => 'user',
                        'action' => 'profile',
                        'admin' => false));
 ?>
    ", function(data)
    {
    if (jQuery.browser.msie)
    {

        alert(container.html()); //returns correct result
        container.empty();
        container.innerHTML = new String(data); 
        alert(data); //shows right output, some html
        alert(container.html()); //is always empty
    }
    else
    {
        container.html(data);
    }
    container.unblock();
    }
    );

    }

    );
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm could you make a jsFiddle

Comment: data is a form element which is being loaded dynamically inside a div which goes by the name .page_content.

Comment: interesting'ly the innerHTML for the container is getting changed. I also have a live query selector for the form which is being loaded. Could that be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/):

```
$(container).replaceWith(data);
```

That is, if `data` is the same `div` content as of the original.

*Note: I am using IE8 to test.*

Comment: does not work. Please see my comment above. Further can you please clarify That is, if data is the same div content as of the original.

Comment: Worked with replaceWith. I think it was a cakephp issue. It did not refresh the javascript.

Comment: Ok, it solved for you, good. I meant that the html format of `data` should be same as the `container`. See the `replaceWith` link reference for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to reset the data within the container, you could do this:

```
container.html(data);
```

Check out what happens when you pass a string to [.html( htmlString )](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

Perhaps your selector is not working properly. If you only want the first element with the .page_content class, why not do:

```
var container = jQuery('.page_content:first');
```

Comment: SO the selector works fine. Thanks for this. does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just resolved the issue by using the following code

```
error: function (data) {
    var resultedHTML = data.responseText;
    $('#Import-1').html(resultedHTML);
    return false;
}
```

response was not working for me. Hence i resolved it using responseText